# Stopping the outer loop from running when inner loop has done the job

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

What I am trying to do is to add a checked checkbox to a form when a value is matching otherwise add a standard not checked one. The checking part is working great and the checked checkbox is added, unfortunately, a second one - not checked is also added resulting in a duplicate entry.

I tried making it an if else statement in the inner loop, but that gives bizarre results (to me). So I am looking for a way to stop the outer loop from creating the duplicate. I am using EJS for Node.

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < sources.sources.length; i++) { %>
            <% for (var j = 0 ; j < source.length ; j++) {  %>
                <% if (source[j] == sources.sources[i].id)  { %>
                    <div class="checkbox-inline">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="<%=sources.sources[i].id%>" checked> <%=sources.sources[i].name%>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                <% } %> 
            <% } %> 
                    <div class="checkbox-inline">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="<%=sources.sources[i].id%>" > <%=sources.sources[i].name%>
                        </label>
                    </div> 
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like there is no need for the inner loop, if I understand your code correctly (no idea what ejs is, but this looks exactly like a lodash template to me). Wouldn't it make more sense to have your template look something like this:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < sources.sources.length; i++) { %>
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <label>
          <input 
              type="checkbox" name="source" value="<%=sources.sources[i].id%>" 
              <% if (source.indexOf(sources.sources[i].id) !== -1) { %>  checked <% } %>
          > <%=sources.sources[i].name%>
        </label>
    </div> 
<% } %>
```

A lot less repetition, better readable imo, and an `indexOf` check must be (potentially) faster then a for loop.

Comment: ...or `source.includes()` - both perform strict equality checks but that shouldn't be an issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your meaning of 'stop the outer loop from running', you can use a [labeled break or continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) to break out of or continue from an outer loop from within the inner loop body:

```
outer: for (...) {
  for (...) {
    if (...) continue outer;
  }
}
```

The same works with EJS by adding a label to the outer loop and `<% continue outer; %>` to the inner loop body.

If I understand you correctly, you don't really want to stop the outer loop from running, but want to continue with the next outer loop iteration - so you would chose `continue`.